# How to run R scripts on Azure and publish diagrams as a webapp

Tags: sql-server, r, azure, shiny

We have a webapp running on Azure with a SQL Server containing a lot of databases. We use the shard mechanism to create a db for each customer.
This works fine.

My colleague is working with RStudio using data I exported from the database (as csv) and he creates some nice looking pages with diagrams and such using R Shiny.

I would like to combine the two, so I don't need to export anymore and our customers can also log in on the `R Shiny webversion` and see the diagrams.

I already did some research and read about Azure Machine Learning, which should support R scripts and I read about SQL Server also supporting R scripts.

But I haven't found anything about publishing the front-end.

I'm looking for a walk-through on setting up the ML server, creating and editing R Scripts that run on that server and showing the output on a website (also in Azure).

Does anybody have experience with this? Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use Azure functions that run your R scripts. From my point of view using Azure ML is not helpful, due to fact that basically it is intended to create a webservice from a predictive model.

You can find a detailed description to run R script from within Azure functions here:
https://github.com/thdeltei/azure-function-r

Hopefully this gets you started
Regards Tom